# When using substring, An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am using String.Substring to pull text out of the middle of a string.  When looking on stackoverflow I see many places where people asked about this for class properties and they said to put static in front of it.  I don't think that would help in my case but I tried anyway and still received the error.  How do I get rid of this error when not using a property?

Here is the code:

```
string filename = String.Substring(1, fileName.IndexOf(')'));
string fileGuid = String.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(')') + 1, 16);

if (String.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('(') + 1, 4) == "html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Substring` from an actual instance of a string

```
string filename = String.Substring(1, fileName.IndexOf(')'));
string fileGuid = String.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(')') + 1, 16);

if (filename.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('(') + 1, 4) == "html")
```

You could also do `String.Contains`

```
if (filename.Contains("html"))
```

or

```
if (filename.Contains("(html"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew that existed

Answer (score 2):

`Substring` isn't a *static* method on the `string` type, it's an *instance* method. If you're trying to extract the substring from `fileName`, you need to use `Substring` on it:

```
string filename = fileName.Substring(1, fileName.IndexOf(')'));
string fileGuid = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(')') + 1, 16);
if (fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('(') + 1, 4) == "html"))
{
    //...
}
```